# Is `builtins.__import__` an attribute or function of the module `builtins`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`builtins.__import__`  can be referred as either an attribute or a function of the module `builtins`.

I wonder if `builtins.__import__` as an attribute of the module and `builtins.__import__` as a function defined in the module are distinct things?

How are they related together?

Thanks.

Comment: Functions are *ordinary* objects, there is no clear distinction. Python simply considers an object to be a dictionary of items, and `__import__` happens to be one of those items, that is callable. Since it is a function, it is both a function and an attribute of the `builtins` module.

Comment: Can I assign to the attribute `builtins.__import__`   a function with a name different from `__import__`, e.g. a function named `myimport`? i.e. can i do `builtins.__import__=myimport`, and then `builtins.__import__(somemodule)` will call `myimport(somemodule)`?

Comment: yes, you can simply write `foo = builtins.__import__` and then later in your program call `foo('bar')`. In Python a class has no fields/properties/methods/... like for instance in C#/Java. It simply has attributes. Python is not interested whether these attributes are functions, integers,...