# Are both `import` statement and `builtin.__import__()` function implemented based on `importlib.__import()` function by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-internals, python-importlib

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

> The purpose of the `importlib` package is two-fold.
>
> One is to provide
>   **the** implementation of **the `import` statement** (and thus, by extension,
>   **[the `__import__()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)**) in Python source code. This provides an
>   implementation of `import` which is portable to any Python interpreter.
>   This also provides an implementation which is easier to comprehend
>   than one implemented in a programming language other than Python.
>
> Two, the components to implement `import` are exposed in this package,
>   making it easier for users to create their own custom objects (known
>   generically as an importer) to participate in the import process.

Does it mean that both the `import` statement and `builtin.__import__()` function are by default implemented based on `importlib.__import()` function?

But https://stackoverflow.com/a/44655619/156458 implies that
`builtins.__import__` is not implemented based on `importlib.__import__` by default.

[https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#**import**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) says that 
`buitlins.__import__` function is invoked by the `import` statement. so if `builtins.__import__` is not implemented based on `importlib.__import__` by default, the `import` statement is not implemented based on `importlib.__import__` by default either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the actual import code is a *port* of the Python code. See the [implementation of the `PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Python/import.c#L1487-L1671) (which `builtins.__import__` is basically a light Python->C wrapper for), which contains the comment:

```c
/* The below code is importlib.__import__() & _gcd_import(), ported to C
   for added performance. */
```

So for *performance reasons*, `import` uses C-optimised code, not the Python implementation of `importlib`. The two implementations are kept in sync, however, if you were to create a pull request touching one, the Python core developers will ask you to update the other too before accepting your changes.

Your use of emphasis leads me to believe you are misreading the documentation; `importlib` is not **the** implementation of the import statement. This is *the implementation of the import statement* **in Python source code**, in contrast to *the implementation of the import statement* **in C code**.

Comment: Thanks. What does "One is to provide the implementation of the import statement (and thus, by extension, the __import__() function) in Python source code " mean about the relation between the three?

Comment: @Tim: Python code is understood by more people; by providing a Python implementation more people can try to understand how this all works and, perhaps, provide improvement suggestions.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is it correct that `buitlins.__import__` attribute is binded to `buitlins.__import__` function by default, and can be rebinded to `importlib.__import` function or any custom function by `buitlins.__import__=<anyFunction>`? [So are ``buitlins.__import__` attribute and ``buitlins.__import__` function two distinct things defined in the module `builtins`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44656019/156458)

Comment: @Tim: yes, you can do `builtins.__import__ = importlib.__import__`, letting you test the Python implementation.

Comment: Is the `import` statement implemented based on `builtins.__import__` function or `builtins.__import__` attribute? I am asking this, because if it is implemented based on the attribute, and when I rebind `builtins.__import__` attribute to a function different from `builtins.__import__` function, the `import` statement will not be implemented based on `builtins.__import__` function but on the different function I rebind to `builtins.__import__` attribute, correct?

Comment: But the `import` statement is used for statically importing only, so it shouldn't be affected by me rebinding `builtins.__import__` attribute to a different function (which if I am correct happens only at run time). So what is the `import` statement implemented based on? Is it implemented based on `builtins.__import__` attribute or function?

Comment: @Tim: `import` the statement uses whatever is assigned to the `builtins.__import__` attribute. The default implementation assigned to that attribute is the C function `builtin__import__`. So yes, you can assign a different callable to that attribute and it'll be used. That's the point of that attribute existing in the first place.

Comment: @Tim: The `import` statement is therefor *hookable*, just like attribute access on instances is hookable by implementing a `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__` method on a class.

Comment: @Tim: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting; the C code is a 'translation' from Python to C code.